# How to Fix the Following Error: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "this.inputStr" is null

Tags: string, null, string-length

```
/* Returns the count of the user's character.  */ 
public int getUserCharCount(){
inputStr = inputStr;
for (int i = 0; i < inputStr.length(); i++) {
  if (inputStr.charAt(i) == userChar) {
  userCharCount ++;
  }
}
return userCharCount;
```

}

By default, inputStr is "" in the Main code. It should be updating to the user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can log inputStr
maybe user set it to null.
also you may check if your variable is null before action.
It hard to say what wrong because you not provide class that hold your variable, and not provide way that class are created and modified.
may be you create new one with null, may be user change value to null